# How would I go about by creating a parser which has the ability to import txt into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, import, text-files

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7NTGXU5R

I have about a hundred of those listened in the same file

I tried working on a php solution, but I wasn't sure how to parse the space, I could only find fgetcsv which does commas

What direction should I head to in order to make sense

I remember some C++ from years ago, I was thinking I do something like a getline, then store the line (or row in our case) into an array
Once that is done, just write a bunch of if statements to go through each line and classify the first element (column) in each array to be the designated 'header'.

Comment: you can specify the delimiter of [`fgetcsv`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and you shouldnt have a problem finding examples on how to parse CSV files on SO. However, the main issue is that there is no fixed delimiters in your case and its unordered information, e.g. there is a layout on that link. Its not a uniformly structured data file. So fgetcsv will likely not help here at all.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing what info you need to extract from the input file(s). Perhaps it would help if you'd specify the table(s) you want to import into.

Comment: Will fgetcsv work with fixed width rows? I copy pasted the entire file into excel and did "fixed width" and it kinda worked. I was trying to import ALL the date into a table, then later when someone wants to write a report or a query at least they have all the information to pick from.

Comment: When I tried to write pseudo code I also got stuck in my sql insert statement. If the columns are not the said (for example, row 1 has 10 elements and row 2 has 20 elements), I'm not sure how to do the %s's. I am going through the oreilly book on php and mysql, it's quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks like that always boil down to a large amount of custom string-munching code. Your best weapons of choice will be regular expressions. Forget about fgetcsv if files look like your file does.

The basic logic might look something like this:

- Fetch all rows of the file via the file function.
- Save each table area to an own array containing the rows:

```
foreach ($filelines as $line)
{
    $lefreportlines[] = trim(substr($line, 0, 93));
    $middlereportlines[] = trim(substr($line, 67, 135));
    ...
}
```

- When you're done, start processing each report as it deserves. For example, the leftmost report might simply be parsed with preg_split('/\s+/', $line);

Either way, you'll have a lot of work to do. Good luck!